# Monitor Amazon RDS for number of rows written in the database

Tags: amazon-rds, amazon-cloudwatch

Amazon RDS has detailed monitoring build-in through CloudWatch. I am trying to get an alarm if more than 10 records are written to the database within last one hour.

Can I set such an alarm in Amazon RDS CloudWatch, if yes how? If not, how can I monitor such a parameter with Relational Databases?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot create such custom alarms in CloudWatch.

But you could use one of your EC2s and place a cron monitor for it, if it is so important to you:

```
#!/bin/bash
rows=`mysql -u{user} -p{password} -BNe 'select count(*) from {db}.{table}'`
if [ $rows -gt 10 ]; then 
     aws ses send-email --from {from} --to {to} --subject "{subject}"  --text "{text}"
fi
```

See additional information on how to use command line AWS here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-set-up.htm